# How to access ADB commands in robot framework? [To fetch device id of connected android device]

Tags: adb, robotframework

I have been trying to access ADB in robot framework. I have tried by importing Process library in the test code. Upon importing 'Process' library I am unable to see any of the keywords associated to the library and all keywords have common error keyword 'No usages found in Project Files'.
(This used to happen as it was redirecting to Multiprocessing Lib rather than Process Lib)

However, upon executing the test it shows the keyword the heading of the test-case set to run
 it runs stays forever and does not proceed further. I have tried it for a max of 30 minutes. Please help me out with this, whether anything needs to be setup.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       Suite description
Library             E:/Automation-Java/SunNXT_Robot/venv/Lib/site-packages/robot/libraries/Process.py
Library             AppiumLibrary
Resource            ../test_data/android_app/test_environment.robot

*** Test Cases ***
RUN THE KEYWORD
     ADB STARTED
     terminate all processes

*** Keywords ***
ADB STARTED
    run process  adb  shell=True
```

Comment: Please don't link to pictures of code on another site. Take the time to copy, paste, and format the code within the body of your question. See [mcve]

Comment: Done @BryanOakley. Please check and let me know if this issue can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

ADB commands can be accessed using the 'Process' Library.

***NOTE: If Process library is added as belows then it would point to Multiprocess library***

```
Library    Process
```

***So we need to import library as following way***

```
Library    ../venv/Lib/site-packages/robot/libraries/Process.py
```

After that we can have access to keywords in Process Library.

Then we can use

```
run process  adb  shell  getprop  ro.serialno  stdout=deviceID.txt
```

to fetch device ID and export the value to a text file.